# Obtaining the PortfolioItem details for User Stories

Tags: rally

I am trying to get the Portfio Item ID and Name for a User Story, using a query like:

```
   var queryConfig = { type : 'HierarchicalRequirement', key : 'stories', fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,PortfolioItem,Parent' };
   var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__', '__PROJECT_OID__', '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
```

and then iterating through it to pull FormattedID, Name and PortfolioItem.FormattedID, but PortfolioItem is always coming back as undefined.
The PortfolioItem the Users Stories are linked to is potentially in another Rally Project (same Workspace) and so I'm not sure if that's it.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Cheers

Martin

Fixed it!!
I needed to add:
       rallyDataSource.setApiVersion('1.37');

before the call to:
       rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, displayUserStories);

Cheers

Martin

Comment: Martin good find on the setApiVersion. Could you post that as an answer to your own question? That's in keeping with StackOverflow etiquette and lets others see that this question has been answered :)

Comment: SDK 1 versions are pinned by default to the like version of WSAPI, so the latest 1.32 SDK is running against WSAPI 1.32.  Good catch.